# search subdirectories and update path variables in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have just moved from Windows environment to Linux, and have been asked to update a project - still learning but tips would be helpful!
I have a directory structure:

```
RootMakefile.mk
.
.--\GUI1 (Folder)
.......|--config(Folder)
.......|--dataprep(Folder)
...............|---makeVar1.mk
.--\GUI2 (Folder)
.......|--config(Folder)
.......|--dataprep(Folder)
...............|....makeVar2.mk.
```

And makeVar1.mk,makeVar2.mk are all similar with just the variables changing the path values:

```
GUI1_ALL:=GUI1/GUI1_generated.txt

GUI2_ALL:=GUI2/GUI2_generated.txt
```

I am trying to make just one makefile at the root so that new GUI folders don't need add new makefiles.

**What I have tried:**
I changed the root makefile as following:

```
    TARGET_FILE := GuiDetails.rb
    ACTIVE_GUIS := $(wildcard GUI*/$(TARGET_FILE)))
    GUIS_OF_INTEREST := $(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS)))
    DATAPREP := dataprep

    GUIS:= $(patsubst %/,%,$(GUIS_OF_INTEREST))
    $(warning The following SMA paths have guis $(GUIS))
    $(foreach GUIS, $(GUIS), $(eval $(call UPDATE_GUI_PATH, $(GUIS), $(DATAPREP))))

$(foreach GUIDEWAYS, $(GUIDEWAYS), $(eval   $(call UPDATE_PATH, $(GUIDEWAYS), $(DATAPREP)))))


define UPDATE_PATH
GUIX_ALL:= $(ROOT)/COMMON/$(1)/$(2)
$(warning GUI1_ALL is set to $(GUIX_ALL))
endef
```

But the value do not show up as expected, the output is:

```
GUIX_ALL is set to 
GUIX_ALL is set to ./COMMON/GUI1/DATAPREP
```

Why is it shifted?

Comment: It's not at all clear what the actual problem you have is.  It would be helpful if you restructured your question as a specific problem to solve: you run "make" and you see result XYZ but what you want instead is ABC, then provide details of what you're doing.  You need a more targeted example: there's too much unknown here (you reference `call` to a lot of variables which have no definition so we don't know what they do).  Also an aside: what is the point of `$(filter %, $(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS)))`?  How is that different than just `$(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS)))`?

Comment: Thanks. I will correct it '$(filter %, $(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS)))' to '$(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS)))'
Sorry, it is just me learning and not getting things right! 
I will try and restructure the question: 
Contained within each folder (GUI1,...GUI(n)) is a makefile to be included in the root, and another in a subdirectory (.\GUIx\dataprep\).
The question is can I get rid of all the makefiles in the subdirectories, and just have one makefile finding the directory structure, and setting up the variables? 
For e.g. 'GUIX_ALL:=$(GUIx/generated.txt)'
(Please ignore the 'call', treat them as variables).

Comment: Ditto for the other use: in general `$(filter %,<foo>)` is identical to just writing `<foo>`: you're just matching all the words in the original list (in any event I can't think of any difference--I guess it condenses any whitespace between words to a single space but that seems unnecessary).  Yes, certainly it's possible to have a single makefile at the top level.  I think a simplified example (rework the question with a simple but run-able example containing just a few directories and a few variables) is needed.

Comment: Thank you MadScientist! I am working on a solution, will update the thread once implemented and tested.

Comment: I have tried to reformat the question, hopefully it makes a little more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you try to use the variable `UPDATE_PATH` (in the `foreach` loop) before you've defined it (later with `define`); when you use it in `foreach`, its value is empty so that is a no-op.  Move the `foreach` so it's after the `define`, not before it.

Second, you need to escape the value of the variables you want to defer until the evaluation.  The value of `UPDATE_PATH` will be expanded once by the `call` function, before it's handed to `eval`.  Things that you don't want expanded until the `eval` (such as the `warning` and `$(GUIX_ALL)` reference) need to be escaped.

Also I assume you mean `$(GUIS)` not `$(GUIDEWAYS)` in the second argument to `foreach`.

I don't know about the `foreach` loop referencing `UPDATE_GUI_PATH` because that's not defined here.

When creating examples it's best if you actually run them and make sure they do what you expected (even if it's not what you wanted) before posting.  Otherwise it's very hard for us to understand what is the real problem you're facing, vs. what's just an inaccurate translation of your problem into the question.

So, something like:

```
define UPDATE_PATH
GUIX_ALL := $(ROOT)/COMMON/$(1)/$(2)
$$(warning GUIX_ALL is set to $$(GUIX_ALL))
endef

$(foreach GUIDEWAYS,$(GUIS),$(eval $(call UPDATE_PATH,$(GUIDEWAYS),$(DATAPREP)))))
```

However, I don't know what purpose this serves since you're just resetting the same variable over and over; at the end the variable `GUIX_ALL` will simply have the value of the last one.  Maybe you wanted to use `+=` here not `:=`?

But if all you want is a list of paths, then why are you using all the complexity of `call` and `eval`?  Why not just set:

```
GUIX_ALL := $(patsubst %,$(ROOT)/common/%/$(DATAPREP),$(GUIS))
```

Comment: Thanks once again MadScientist! Unfortunately the question was a simplification of a more complex problem. But your answer has taken me a long way! There are a lot of variables set with the path, and then they are called to generate code through xml files in each folder (there are eight folders in total).

Comment: I have another question though, I have a predefind function (in an include.mk):

`CANONICAL_PATH=$(subst $(abspath .)/,,$(abspath $(1)))`
however, when I call it:


`GUIX_ALL := $(ROOT)/COMMON/$(1)/$(2)
GUI1_GWM:=$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$(GUIX_ALL)/gwm.xml)
$$(warning GUI1_GWM is set to $$(GUI1_GWM))`


I don't see the values printed, but if I expand the function, I get the values:


`GUI1_GWM:= $$(subst $$(abspath .)/,,$$(abspath $$(GUIX_ALL)/gwm.xml))`


the function is being called all over the project, why would it just fail in the update that I am making?

Comment: It's not possible to discuss these things in comments: the limited formatting makes it impossible to understand the context. Please ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Follow up question posted as: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934636/why-does-an-escaped-variable-work-and-not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934636/why-does-an-escaped-variable-work-and-not)