# Why does an escaped variable $$ work and not $

Tags: makefile

This is a follow up question to the previous one I had asked in the thread:

[search subdirectories and update path variables in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812768/search-subdirectories-and-update-path-variables-in-makefile)

In the following:

There is a rules makefile which adds various standard defines,
Include.mak. It has a define:

```
RESOLVED_PATH=$(subst $(abspath .)/,,$(abspath $(1)))
```

It is being used in another makefile:

```
include Include.mak

ROOT:=.
define UPDATE_GUI
d:= $$(strip $(1))
GUI_FOLDER:= $(ROOT)/$(d)
GUI_ALL:=$(call RESOLVED_PATH,$(GUI_FOLDER)/$(d)_generated.txt)
$$(warning GUI_ALL is set to $$(GUI_ALL))
endef

TARGET_FILE:= ProjectParms.rb

ACTIVE_GUIS = $(wildcard GUI*/$(TARGET_FILE))
GUIS_OF_INTEREST = $(dir $(ACTIVE_GUIS))
GUIS= $(patsubst %/,%,$(GUIS_OF_INTEREST))
$(foreach GUI, $(GUIS), $(eval  $(call UPDATE_GUI, $(GUI))))
```

This does not give the output as desired, but if I expand the same in the line:

```
GUI_ALL:=$$(subst $$(abspath .)/,,$$(abspath $$(GUI_FOLDER)/$$(d)_generated.txt)

$$(warning GUI_ALL is set to $$(GUI_ALL))
```

It works fine, can someone tell me why? The $(call RESOLVED_PATH, Param ) is being used throughout the make project in different places (though no $(warning '') is being used anywhere else, I am just using that for a quick sanity check.

Comment: What is the output you get?  What is the output you desired?

Comment: I was expecting $(d) to be expanded, **GUI1/GUI1_generated.txt** and then **GUI2/GUI2_generated.txt**.

I got **/_generated.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape *everything* in the function except the actual `call` arguments.  Sometimes you don't want this but almost all the time you do.  So it should be:

```
define UPDATE_GUI
d := $$(strip $(1))
GUI_FOLDER := $$(ROOT)/$$(d)
GUI_ALL := $$(call RESOLVED_PATH,$$(GUI_FOLDER)/$$(d)_generated.txt)
$$(warning GUI_ALL is set to $$(GUI_ALL))
endef
```

For debugging, you can replace the `eval` function with the `info` function; this will print out for you what the makefile syntax is that `eval` would work on.  If you do that, you'll see that by the time `eval` gets the text to parse it's already wrong, because `call` expanded it.  E.g.,

```
$(foreach GUI,$(GUIS),$(info $(call UPDATE_GUI,$(GUI))))
```

*ETA*

I will point out that you can greatly simplify this by removing the `call` function altogether.  In order to do this you'll have to be OK with the `UPDATE_GUI` define being tightly bound with the `foreach`.  Since you're just passing one argument to `call` anyway, you can just not do that and put the `GUI` variable (the loop variable in `foreach`) directly into the `UPDATE_GUI` define; then you don't need call.  Like this:

```
define UPDATE_GUI
d := $(strip $(GUI))
GUI_FOLDER := $(ROOT)/$(d)
GUI_ALL := $(call RESOLVED_PATH,$(GUI_FOLDER)/$(d)_generated.txt)
$(warning GUI_ALL is set to $(GUI_ALL))
endef

$(foreach GUI,$(GUIS),$(eval $(UPDATE_GUI)))
```

Comment: Note my second sentence: not ALL of these escapes are needed.  But they don't hurt, either, and it can simplify the effort if you just escape them all except the `call` arguments.  It's left as an exercise to the reader to determine which escapes are really necessary and which are not... once you really grok that you'll be well on your way to mastery of `eval` and `call` and makefile expansion in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your inputs MadScientist! I will try them now and update!

Comment: Thanks for all your help MadScientist. I was making newbie errors and eventually managed to get things finished! A lot of your suggestions helped!